# How to play a specific video on a React native ScrollView carousel?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, scrollview

I have a scrollview that has as a child an array of video components. It displays on the UI a carousel of videos. I would like the user to be able to click a play button that is above the video and play that video, but the way my logic is set, all the videos play together because the condition to play the video lives in a react useState.

see the code:

```
const VideosView = (props) => {
    const videoClips = props.route.params.data;
    const [state, setState] = React.useState(0);
    const [play, setPlay] = React.useState(false);

    return (
        <>
            <SafeAreaView pointerEvents='box-none' style={styles.root}>
                <Header
                    goBack={() => props.navigation.goBack()}
                    title={state === 0 ? 'RYGGRöRLIGHET' : 'STYRKA & BALANS'}
                />
                <View style={styles.paragraphsContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>
                        {state === 0 ? 'Ryggrörlighet' : 'Styrka & Balans'}
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
                        'Utför övningen i ca 5 min för bästa resultat.'
                    </Text>
                    <View style={styles.circlesContainer}>
                        {renderImages.map((_, index) => {
                            return (
                                <TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={() => setState(0)}>
                                    <View
                                        style={[
                                            styles.circles,
                                            { opacity: index === state ? 1 : 0.5 }
                                        ]}
                                    />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            );
                        })}
                    </View>
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
            <View style={styles.scrollViewContainer}>
                <ScrollView
                    bounces={false}
                    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                    scrollEventThrottle={30}
                    onScroll={({ nativeEvent }) => {
                        const slide = Math.ceil(
                            nativeEvent.contentOffset.x / nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.width
                        );
                        if (slide !== state) {
                            setState(slide);
                        }
                    }}
                    horizontal>
                    {videoClips.map((video, index) => (
                        <View style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
                            {!play && (
                                <TouchableOpacity
                                    style={{
                                        position: 'absolute',
                                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)',
                                        alignSelf: 'center',
                                        top: 130,
                                        width: 160,
                                        height: 160,
                                        borderRadius: 500,
                                        zIndex: 4000
                                    }}
                                    onPress={() => setPlay(true)}></TouchableOpacity>
                            )}
                            <Video

                                shouldPlay={play}
                                key={index}
                                source={{
                                    uri: video
                                }}
                                resizeMode='cover'
                                style={{ width: wp('100%'), height: hp('100%') }}
                            />
                        </View>
                    ))}
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        </>
    );
};
```

I would like the user to click a button and play one video, use the carousel to go to next video, click play and play the next video.

Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the play state from **Boolean** to **Number** you will probably solve your problem. Here is how:

```
    const [videoBeingDisplayedIndex, setVideoBeingDisplayedIndex] = React.useState(5);
    const [play, setPlay] = React.useState(5); // If it is equals to the video id the video should play, else it should not
...
    <Button onClick={() => setPlay(videoBeingDisplayedIndex)}>
        Play Video
    </Button>
    <VideoCarousel>
        {
            myVideoList.map((video, index) => {
                return (
                   <Video 
                       content={video} 
                       index={index} 
                       play={play === index} // Check if the current play state is equals to the video unique id
                   />
                );
            })
        }
    </VideoCarousel>
...
```

**PS.:** please, have in mind that this snippet is abstracting the react-native elements and focusing on the problem.